# Coefficient of coupling in coupled oscillators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

[image]

My question is how and on which things this quantity *p*,the extent of coupling depends?

Why the force exerted by one on other is proportional to its acceleration?

Comment: @sammy gerbil but i can easily see the image clicking on the blue coloured sentence(the link)

Answer (score 0):

The coupling force depends on the coupling mechanism, which is not identified in your problem.

If the coupling mechanism is a spring, the coupling force depends on the extension of the spring, which depends on the difference in the displacements of the masses. Likewise if the coupling mechanism is electrostatic repulsion or attraction. It does not depend on their accelerations. eg If the masses swing in unison, there is a constant or zero coupling force, whereas the acceleration of each mass varies.

If the coupling force is transmitted by the tension in the pendulum strings or rods, this varies with the acceleration of each mass.

The strength of coupling is also likely to depend on how far the linkage $O_1O_2$ is from the pivots. The closer it is to them, the smaller the torque which the linkage exerts, resulting in weaker coupling.

You should ask the person who wrote the coupling as being proportional to acceleration why this has been done.